# Occasional ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error when hitting Node.js Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, load-balancing, connection-reset

I recently deployed a node.js based site into load balanced servers(windows).
(Not sure if Node.js or load balancer matters in the case, but want to share the information)

When I hit the url in Chrome, I sometimes get ERR_Connection_Reset error:
For example: mysite.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

But if I try to hit mysite.com/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js in browser, it works. Which means the path doesn't have problem.

When I hit the url in IE, I sometimes get XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff.

I've been scratching my head for days, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you using? [This patch](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3595) fixed a problem with idle sockets throwing ECONNRESET errors and it shipped in 4.4.0 and 5.4.0, upgrading fixed the issues for me.

Comment: Hmmmm, the working server has 5.7.1, but the not working servers have 5.3.   Let me quickly update the version and see if that works

Comment: Updated one of the load balanced servers to 6.2.1, but same issue still happens(in that server). I can't update the other server now, but will try again tomorrow.